# Flowcharts - a way of drawing GOTOs?

Tags: language-agnostic, goto, flowchart

**Background**: I've inherited a proof-of-concept project which gives the user a drawing canvas on which to construct a flowchart. It then tries to generate some procedural code from the flowchart.

I have serious doubts whether this can ever be truly successful, partly because there are so many bugs, but fundamentally because...

**Question**: Aren't flowcharts just a way of drawing GOTOs? And therefore isn't it necessarily going to be difficult to generate well-structured procedural code from a flowchart?

Comment: `if`, `while`, `for` and `switch` are also just a way of generating GOTOs. It's not critical that the low level code use gotos. What's important is that humans don't use gotos. The compiler (in your case the flowchart compiler) wouldn't be confused by gotos. It's the human brain that tend to miss bugs when gotos are used in code.

Comment: Also, `if`, `while`, `for` and `switch` are merely just different ways of saying `goto` in a more structured way. Mostly, flowcharts tend to represent `if` a lot and sometimes `while`. So generate `if`, `while`, `for` and `switch` if you really don't want to generate `goto`

Comment: @slebetman - yes, I know exactly what you're getting at. These neater constructs `while`, `for`, etc., are combinations of `goto`s. But consider a function call - it always returns control back to the point it was called from. That's _two_ `goto`s. The flowchart allows the user to place them individually. While it's _possible_ to write well-structured code with `goto`s, it's not enforced.

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054233/do-experienced-programmers-still-use-flowcharts-to-work-out-the-order-of-operati) cites [this article](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=323161), which I found interesting, but it doesn't exactly answer my specific question. In fact I suspect the answer to my specific question is the reason the article finds flowcharts aren't much use.

Comment: There's generally no semantic support for functions in flow charts. Flow charts are all about `if` and `loops`. Flow charts are a visualization of finite automata. In a way, they server the same purpose as regular expressions. IEC1131 "programming language" do have functions in the flow chart language: function definitions start with a `<start>` block and return on an `<end>` block while a function is compiled into an action block with only one entry and exit: `--[my_function]-->`. But that's more like connecting flowcharts together. A single flowchart is a single function.

Comment: Sigh.. it's hard to find good documentation on IEC1131 on the net. I guess it's partly because IEC sells the standard document and have teams of lawyers to enforce their copyright online. IEC1131 is a standard for how PLC programming should work (in a standard way, there are PLCs on the market that have non-standard programming languages like lua and java which are considered non-standard in the world of industrial automation)

Comment: Flowchart is one of the programming languages available under IEC1131. I can't confirm how it is worldwide but in my country it's rarely used. Most people use ladder logic (another graphical programming language). That's because most technicians who program PLCs aren't engineers or software developers. They're electrical technicians and they learned ladder diagrams to make sense of complex electrical wiring such as stair lights.

Comment: @slebetman re function calls, fair enough, but that's not the only place where other artifacts are required to create structured code (see my recently-posted answer). My point was that there's a whole lot of "other stuff" goes on when structured code generates low level `goto`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62149/discussion-between-outstandingbill-and-slebetman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own answer, which I won't accept (at least for a few weeks) because I really want other people's opinions.

Algorithms expressed using flowcharts are more akin to code written using `goto`s than structured languages such as C#, Pascal or Java.

The flowchart connector can sometimes represent a sequence of statements in code.  At other times it can represent part of a structured construct such as `īf`, `while`, etc. But it is more generally representative of `goto` for these reasons:

1. The connector's function is simply to transfer control from one statement to another. This is exactly what `goto` does.
2. The target of the connector can be any node on the page.  Similarly, a `goto` can target any statement in scope.

This closer similarity between flowcharts and code with `goto`s can be illustrated by comparing the effects of a small change.  Let's look at two versions of a flowchart and see how they can be represented in both structured code and code with `goto`s.

[image: voting flowcharts]

The only difference between the two versions of the flowchart is in the target of the "registered to vote? No" connector.

Here's Version A as structured code:

```
REM Version A
decide who to vote for
IF registered to vote THEN
    vote
END IF
```

Version A's structured code has to be significantly refactored to get Version B:

```
REM Version B
DO
    decide who to vote for
UNTIL registered to vote
vote
```

Here's Version A as code with `goto`s

```
REM Version A
decide who to vote for
IF registered to vote THEN GOTO VOTE
GOTO FINISH
VOTE:
vote
FINISH:
```

Version B of the code with `goto`s is very similar:

```
REM Version B
DECIDE:
decide who to vote for
IF registered to vote THEN GOTO VOTE
GOTO DECIDE
VOTE:
vote
FINISH:
```

The changes to the code with `goto`s are similar to the changes made in the flowchart: change the connector's target, change the `goto` target.  By contrast, the changes required in the structured code bear no resemblance to the changes made to the flowchart: Version A does something *if* a condition is true whereas Version B does something else *until* the condition is true.

So the flowchart is more closely represented by code with `goto`s.  There's a closer correspondence between the flowchart components and the `goto` code components.  The flowchart connectors correspond directly to the `goto`s in the code.

**Conclusion**

The intent of the algorithm can be changed significantly by making a small change to the flowchart.  So you might say that while a flowchart can represent the mechanics of an algorithm, it doesn't do a great job of robustly representing the intent.

This is because the purpose of flowchart connectors is to represent the low-level *how*, rather than *what* the algorithm is trying to achieve.  By contrast, the constructs in structured code such as `if`, `while`, etc. are more about *what*.

So to answer the question: yes, drawing flowchart connectors is a way of representing `goto`s.

---

**Footnote**

As slebetman commented on the question, there are `goto`s behind the well-structured code we all write in Java, C#, etc., at the machine code level at least.  But that's only part of the story.  In structured code, the low level `goto` is always used in a carefully controlled way, and often in association with other artefacts like labels which are not seen in the high level code.

Comment: A flowchart can't connect to more than one "next step" without a condition because flowcharts generally don't support parallel execution. A flowchart connector therefore is just the next line in a text file and what it points to is just a function. No unstructured code there.

Comment: @slebetman - So flowcharts without conditions are not unstructured.  Um, true. Sorry, I don't see what point you're making.

Comment: It really doesn't look like anyone else is going to put forward an answer, so I'll accept my own.

Answer (score 0):

I was write a programing guide for teens, and I think goto is very simple to explain the program's flow, so I used goto to replace while/if/for...

When I draw flow chart, I use a circle with a label to describe it.